# как получить POJOиз нестандарного JSON , с помощью GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{"params": [ 
  {"beer": "Amstel"},
  {"cost": "12", "minTimes": 5}, // price and bying times
  {"sells": 12, "amount": 40},   //sells count & sells amount
  {"refused": 3}                 //refused sells
 ]}
```

Ребята, подскажите как превратить этот JSON запрос в POJO объекты.
"beer" может быть несколько штук в запросе. Использую GSON,
вот так работает;

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jo = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray paramsArray = jo.get("params").getAsJsonArray();
```

Как теперь это десериализовать?
тут нет явных объектов Sells вида - sells={"cost": "12", "minTimes": 5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если массив `params` это на самом деле массив ключей одной POJO то можно сделать так:

1. создаем пустой JsonObject
2. проходим по каждому элементу массива params
3. у каждого элемента проходим по каждому ключу
4. в JsonObject из п.0 добавляем ключ + значение
5. превращаем наш JsonObject в POJO

```
public class DemoSpringSecApplication {
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class MyPojo {
        private String beer;
        private int cost;
        private int minTimes;
        private int sells;
        private int amount;
        private int refused;
        //getter..setter..constructors..toString
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String jsonStr = "{\"params\": [ \n" +
                "  {\"beer\": \"Amstel\"},\n" +
                "  {\"cost\": \"12\", \"minTimes\": 5}, // price and bying times\n" +
                "  {\"sells\": 12, \"amount\": 40},   //sells count & sells amount\n" +
                "  {\"refused\": 3}                 //refused sells\n" +
                " ]}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jo = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class);
        JsonObject pojo = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray paramsArray = jo.get("params").getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : paramsArray) {
            if (jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
                JsonObject obj = ((JsonObject) jsonElement);
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> jsonEntry : obj.entrySet()) {
                    pojo.add(jsonEntry.getKey(), jsonEntry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        MyPojo myPojo = gson.fromJson(pojo.toString(), MyPojo.class);
        System.out.println("JSON:"+pojo);
        System.out.println("POJO:"+myPojo);
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
JSON:{"beer":"Amstel","cost":"12","minTimes":5,"sells":12,"amount":40,"refused":3}
POJO:DemoSpringSecApplication.MyPojo(beer=Amstel, cost=12, minTimes=5, sells=12, amount=40, refused=3)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @КонстантинКарантин поставьте пожалуйста галочку что ответ верный :)

Comment: Спасибо, ещё не умею пользоваться сайтом )))